# parent & child browsers view got switched during automated execution by HP UFT

Tags: hp-uft

I am facing a strange issue with my test automation scripts when executed through HP UFT 12.01

Our AUT is a web based application developed in actimize. During my test flow, lets say at 5th step i need to invoke a popup browser (child) from my main page. The new popup browser will not have any menus or back/fwd buttons.

3 out of 10 executions, during 5th step my main browser gets refreshed to invoke the popup and when popup rendered fully, contents and views got switched now. i.e., main browser has the contents which are supposed to display in popup window (with menu bar and back/fwd buttons) and pop-up window has main page contents (without menu bar, back/fwd buttons) & state when i performed click operation.

This is strange and i could not really conclude if its browser issue or UFT issue. I have also checked with functional team and they never faced, so this is happening only through UFT execution and speculating it could be UFT issue.. any help pls?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be either:

1) an actual bug in your UAT

2) a problem with QTP object identification.

If it's #2, here's some things to check.  First, make sure that QTP can correctly and reliably identify the two different "browsers".  (i.e. while both are on the screen, use the "Highlight in Application" button found the Object Repository window while each of the objects is selected.  I would try this for both a normal run and immediately after the browsers get switched (use a break point if necessary)

If there is a problem with QTP identifying the windows incorrectly, then you might want to add additional Description properties to the test object in the OR so that it can lock onto the right one more reliably.  I usually use GUISpy to spy on something on the page, then in Object hierarchy I click on the top object (the browser), then click "Copy identification properties to the Clipboard" button, then paste the results into a notepad.  Find one of those properties that uniquely identifies the browser objects from anything else.  Sometimes I have to use the URL property (with some REGEX magic to isolate the specific page without making it TOO specific)